# extract mean track from several time series of XY data

Tags: matlab, regression, mean, spline

I have 11,719 XY coordinate pairs obtained from 6 different instruments that track ocean currents (they measure UTC time, longitude, latitude, temperature). These instruments drifted along, so there are no repeat measures at the same location. I need to extract a "mean track" from that XY data. Here is the dataset: http://dropbox.com/s/dg0psl3hnmilg44/summerdrifters.csv

I was thinking of a regression line but the mean track i want to get is obviously not linear. I tried using different fitting functions, such as smoothing splines through `cftool(lon,lat)`, but it is not the most convenient way as I need to fraction the data into subsets, then somehow merge the different functions.

Comment: So you have 5 different time series of xy coordinates, right? If you don't have a model of the "track", the simplest approach would be to first average across the 5 time series at the same time (if this is defined), and secondly to average over a sliding window of a fixed extent in time. If you have a plot of your data, post it here so we can get an idea.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I tried the simplest approach but the problem is that the 5 tracks were measured at different times (1 to 2 weeks apart), and the length (in space and time) of each track is different too. I have plotted all the data in Matlab using scatter (i'll try to post that) and looking into using a smoother. I'll also try to post the the dataset so you can see. Thanks again for helping out!

Comment: You're welcome. You could also, if that's ok, post the data.

Comment: hmmm... no obvious way to attach a doc to the thread..

Comment: it's in my dropbox.. let me know if you can access it.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/p7hq8q5c20g556d/summerRunningMean.csv

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/561ar9zgm7absns/Screen%20shot%202013-10-30%20at%2010.18.37%20AM.png

Comment: After plotting your data, I'm not sure you need temporal smoothing, and I'm not clear about what you are trying to achieve...

Comment: i am trying to get a spatial representation only of the data, but what makes it hard is that the dataset is in 3-D (has time). When smoothing the lower half (lat<2) with smoothing splines I get a nice result, but the problem is the upper part, where the drifters veer towards the E

Comment: Ok, but how would such a representation look like? Do you want a parametrized curve, or just something that looks nice when plotted?

Comment: one or a series of parametrized curves, as I need to get the statistics (variance).

Comment: Still thinking about it, haven't come up with a great idea yet. In the meantime, it would be good if you could edit your question to: - include the link to the dataset - correct the numbers: 6 sequences, 11719 data points. - explain how you did your spline approach - explain more precisely want kind of statistics (variance of what) you need. On SO, Q&A are not just there to help the poster, but also to be useful to readers who find the question via search.

Comment: I have added a file, summerdrifters.csv to my dropbox: https://www.dropbox.com/s/dg0psl3hnmilg44/summerdrifters.csv

Comment: it gives the full dataset. the time series is smooth, except for drifter OIST...76. I am considering dropping it as it was released in the middle of the ocean. So keeping 68-72, one gets the plot you give below. What I am looking for is a way to get one single track that averages the lats and longs with a window that slides not over time but over either lat or lon, depending on where you are in the plot. I tried to fraction the data in chunks, using scatter(lon, lat) and then cftool.

Comment: If i keep the scatterplot as depicted in your plot, there is no function that can smooth the data. However, when fractioned (using exclusion function in cftool) into different "chunks" (e.g. lat<2 and 128.5<lon<133, for the lower section of the plot) then I can use different functions to get to an acceptable fit, for instance: https://www.dropbox.com/s/rotpaur7elziqqk/sspline_lat%3C2.png for the data corresponding to the chunk given above.  My idea now is to get the best fit functions for the other chunks (I have 4) and merge them together. That would yield the "mean" track I am looking for.

Comment: I think I have found a way to go without spline. Wait a sec.

Comment: I've formatted the dataset to be used in matlab, using csvread: https://www.dropbox.com/s/dg0psl3hnmilg44/summerdrifters.csv the first col is time, 2nd is instrument no., 3rd is lat, 4th is lon and 5th col is velocity.

Comment: Have a look, I posted my approach. I hope you can use it. Would you please do the update of the question I mentioned above?

Comment: can I contact you via email?

Comment: Ok, here comes the update to the question: I have data from 6 instruments that measured latitude (lat), longitude (lon) & ocean current velocity at different periods. These instruments drifted along, so there are no repeat measures at the same location. I plotted the two dimensions lat and lon of the 6 drifters (11719 data points), yielding 6 trajectories, and tried to obtain a mean trajectory for the 6 drifters. Here is the dataset: https://www.dropbox.com/s/dg0psl3hnmilg44/summerdrifters.csv

Comment: (col.1 is time -excel format, 2 is instrument #, 3 is lat, 4 is lon, 5 is velocity in m.s). I tried using different fitting functions, such as smoothing splines through cftool(lon,lat), but it is not the most convenient way as I need to fraction the data into subsets, then somehow merge the different functions. A. Donda came up with the answer. Many thanks! Corto

Comment: Thanks! I meant, edit the original question (click "edit" below the question), but don't worry, I just did it for you. My edit will take some time to show up though because its being reviewed by others. Glad I could help, it was an interesting problem.

Comment: Hi A. Donda. I looked at the result of the mean track, and there is a problem, as in the higher latitudes (>2) the "mean track" (black line) does not realistically represent the mean of the two remaining tracks, as it should do in oceanography. I don't know how to work around this. Any insight?

Comment: That's due to the smoothing. Try a smaller `span`, or don't smooth at all. I'm not sure anymore it was a good idea to smooth.

Comment: I added to answer to reflect this, and now first give the unsmoothe mean track.

Comment: Hi Corto, if you feel that I've helped you that much, I'd be honored to be acknowledged – but don't feel obligated. If you do, please send me the link to the publication. Feel free to ask again. If you make another question and think I could help, you could comment here to draw my attention.

Comment: Hi A. Donda. Thanks for getting back to me. Is there a way we could correspond more privately? my email is: cortoeldemalta_at_yahoo.com.ar

Comment: Hi A. Donda
Here’s the second part of the problem. I have little animals that disperse over the water surface but not in a passive way, as they can swim, albeit not very fast. 
I did field trials and determined that they all swim towards the N, at varying speeds of 0.01 to about 2.0 m.s. Further, I measured the dispersal vector of these animals under different current conditions (by tracking the animals at the same time I was tracking the currents with the instruments). For example, in a current flowing between -90 and -45 degrees

Comment: (=direction of the current vector, given as a “ direction category”) and at velocity of 0.3-0.47 m.s (=magnitude of the current vector, given as a “velocity category”), the corresponding animal vector characteristics (= deviation from the current’s track) is -10 degrees (direction of the “animal vector”) and 0.25 m.s (magnitude of the “animal vector”). My trials enabled to determine the animal vector characteristics for most current scenarios and the corresponding 95% confidence intervals.So, for this model, the animal is entrained in the mean current (determined from the 5 drifter tracks)

Comment: but due to its own sustained swimming, (which is always towards the north, or 0 degrees) it is not following exactly the current’s path. So the question is where does an animal end up after a given amount of time? 
The idea of the model is that it should give at each time-step along the mean current’s track, the corresponding position of the animal as it deviates from (or follows) the current’s track. So, at t+1, the “animal vector”, which is selected by the model to match the corresponding current characteristics (velocity and bearing categories),

Comment: will be summed to the previous vector at time=t. At each time step, the animal is expected to deviate a little more from the current’s track, unless the current flows in the same direction as the animal’s swimming direction. Associated with each animal vector are the 95% confidence intervals of the direction (in degrees) and the magnitude (velocity, in m.s). So in the end, I hope to get for the entire length of the mean track, the dispersal route of the animal with the 95% confidence interval. The result should look like the projected path of a hurricane 
Any idea on how to code this?

Comment: The data is in my dropbox: summer_disp_model.csv.
Rec=record number; v_cat=velocity category of the current; b_cat=direction category of current; delta_t=time elapsed, in seconds, between 2 successive coordinate pairs/records; phi=animal vector direction (degrees); phi_low=lower 95%. confidence limit (degrees); phi_up= upper 95% confidence limit (degrees); vel=animal vector magnitude (m.s-1); vel_low=lower 95% confidence limit (m.s-1); vel_up= upper 95% confidence limit (m.s-1). Directions are angles on a 180 degree scale: N=0, E=90, S=180/-180, W=-90). 
Also, see schematic in dropbox.

Comment: Links: https://www.dropbox.com/s/hnsaaqc3wwq5wpo/summer_disp_model.csv

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/v22tz2e01vxez8n/model_schematic.jpg

Comment: Hi Corto, interesting, I'll have a look, maybe not today but soon. But, wouldn't it be better to post this as a new question?

Comment: Sure! Will do that. I also realized the dataset has an error that I'll fix today. Take care.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [data set](https://www.dropbox.com/s/p7hq8q5c20g556d/summerRunningMean.csv) has 11719 points. The continuous segments can be detected like this

```
d = load('summerRunningMean.csv');

% detect continuous parts
s = sqrt(sum(diff(d)' .^ 2));
ind = [0, find(s > 100 * mean(s)), size(d, 1)];
```

which results in 6 segments with lengths from 534 to 4255 points.

Plotting the tracks superimposed in space

```
for i = 1 : 6
    x = d(ind(i) + 1 : ind(i + 1), 1);
    y = d(ind(i) + 1 : ind(i + 1), 2);
    plot(x, y)
    hold all
end
xlabel x
ylabel y
axis equal
```

gives this result

[image: tracks in space]

and shows that the tracks have roughly the same shape, and that all but one of them start at the same place.

Superimposition of the time series however shows that the movement along that shape occurs at different speeds:

[image: superimposed time series]

The problem with doing statistics for this data is therefore that there is no common reference point to assign data points from different tracks to each other.

In the following I excluded track #6 because it has a different starting point than the others.

---

One approach to define such a common reference is to compute the *curve length* along the track:

```
l = [0 ; cumsum(sqrt(diff(x) .^ 2 + diff(y) .^ 2))];
```

Plotting over this length instead of over time makes the x and y coordinates more similar and therefore comparable:

[image: coordinates over curve length]

From this result, one can compute the mean and other statistics. To actually do it, the data have to be reparametrized by interpolation:

```
li = 0 :0.001: l(end);
xi = interp1(l, x, li);
yi = interp1(l, y, li);
```

Now, for each of the tracks we have a common reference and can store the transformed data in common data matrices:

```
n = numel(li);
xp(1 : n, i) = xi;
yp(1 : n, i) = yi;
```

where `i` is the track index. The matrices `xp` and `yp` have to be initialized to NaNs because the tracks have different lengths. Then, statistics can be computed, e.g. the mean:

```
xm = nanmean(xp, 2);
ym = nanmean(yp, 2);
```

The resulting mean track together with the original tracks:

[image: added mean track]

---

To further improve the agreement between the tracks, one could smooth them in order to reduce random variations (`span = 5000` seems to work well):

```
xs = smooth(xi, span);
ys = smooth(yi, span);
```

After that, the curve length parameter has to be recomputed:

```
l = [0 ; cumsum(sqrt(diff(xs) .^ 2 + diff(ys) .^ 2))];
```

The result:

[image: smoothed coordinates over curve length]

The agreement underlying the common reference has clearly been improved. The data have again to be reparametrized

```
li = 0 :0.001: l(end);
xsi = interp1(l, xs, li);
ysi = interp1(l, ys, li);
```

the result stored in the common data matrices

```
n = numel(li);
xp(1 : n, i) = xsi;
yp(1 : n, i) = ysi;
```

and the mean computed

```
xm = nanmean(xp, 2);
ym = nanmean(yp, 2);
```

The resulting mean track together with the original tracks:

[image: added smoothed mean track]

The result looks much smoother. However, the smoothing has reduced the circumference of the large loop at the end of two of the tracks, and as a result the "mean track" does no longer lie between the original tracks. The trade-off between smoothness and closeness to the original tracks can be regulated via the value of `span`.

---

The full code to generate the last figure is included here; in order to reproduce the unsmoothed version, set `span = 1;`.

```
d = load('summerRunningMean.csv');

% detect tracks as continuous segments
s = sqrt(sum(diff(d)' .^ 2));
ind = [0, find(s > 100 * mean(s)), size(d, 1)];
% remove 6th track because itis an outlier
ind = ind(1 : end - 1);
N = size(ind, 2) - 1;

% smoothing parameter
span = 5000;

xp = nan(13000, N);   % I know, hardcoded, not nice.
yp = nan(13000, N);
for i = 1 : N
    % extract data
    x = d(ind(i) + 1 : ind(i + 1), 1);
    y = d(ind(i) + 1 : ind(i + 1), 2);

    % determine length along curve
    % to use as curve parameter
    l = [0 ; cumsum(sqrt(diff(x) .^ 2 + diff(y) .^ 2))];

    % reparametrize by interpolation
    li = 0 :0.001: l(end);
    xi = interp1(l, x, li);
    yi = interp1(l, y, li);

    % smooth to remove small deviations
    xs = smooth(xi, span);
    ys = smooth(yi, span);

    % determine length along smoothed curve
    % as improved curve parameter
    l = [0 ; cumsum(sqrt(diff(xs) .^ 2 + diff(ys) .^ 2))];

    % again, reparametrize by interpolation
    li = 0 :0.001: l(end);
    xsi = interp1(l, xs, li);
    ysi = interp1(l, ys, li);

    % store
    n = numel(li);
    xp(1 : n, i) = xsi;
    yp(1 : n, i) = ysi;

    plot(x, y)
    axis equal
    hold all
end

% compute mean
xm = nanmean(xp, 2);
ym = nanmean(yp, 2);

% plot mean
plot(xm, ym, 'k', 'LineWidth', 2)
xlabel x
ylabel y
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`scatter(X,Y)`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatter.html) to plot your data and [`cftool(X,Y)`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/cftool.html) to interactively play with different models. Note that `cftool` plots your data with a superimposed regression line.